# ahk how to keep visible a window though not active

Tags: windows, autohotkey, visible

The below script works but minimizes a screen inactive, but I would like to keep the inactive window visible. what should I do?

```
F9::
      IfWinExist ahk_class Forge10MDIClass
      WinMove ahk_class Forge10MDIClass
      WinActivate ahk_class Forge10MDIClass
Send {space} ;; pauses audio file (toggles)
Send !{Esc} ;; Alt + Esc in Windows 8; but it is minimizing and I dont want that
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in 2 different ways:

First: Store the active window and switch back after toggling the audio file

```
F9::
    WinGet, active_id, ID, A
    IfWinExist ahk_class Forge10MDIClass
    {
        WinActivate ahk_class Forge10MDIClass
        Send {space} ;; pauses audio file (toggles)
        WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
    }
    Return
```

Second: Use `ControlSend` to send <kbd>Space</kbd> directly to the window without having to activate it.

```
F9::ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Space}, ahk_class Forge10MDIClass
```

**Note:** I do not have this software, so I cannot confirm that `ControlSend` works properly with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the frist way and it is not working. Sound Forge is still minimizing.Please let me know how to implement the second way. Is it only one line?

Comment: try adding a `sleep 100` statement after `WinActivate ahk_class Forge10MDIClass` - maybe it is a sluggish window.

Comment: Moreover looking closely at the script I don't see really what can help solve the problem, that is to keep my Soundforge screen visible but not active. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: No, you CAN do it.  A window can be visible and not active.  Just try it: open two notepad files side by side.  When you click on one, it becomes active, but the other one is still visible even though it has completely lost focus.

Comment: ok, but that is not going on in this case of Word and Sound Forge. Please any way to do it?

Comment: If you open the two windows one after the other and then activate one of them, the other will be visible so long as the one on top does not cover it.